# null reference exception with linq .where clause

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, null

I'm trying to get a property from an array of object that can be null (the array) and I'm always getting a null reference exception.

How can I tell LINQ to not process it in case it's null or to return an empty string?

```
foreach (Candidate c in candidates) {
   results.Add(new Person 
      { 
         firstName = c.firstname, //ok
         lastName = c.Name, //ok

         // contactItems is an array of ContactItem
         // so it can be null that's why I get null exception 
         // when it's actually null
         phone = c.address.contactItems.Where( ci => ci.contactType == ContactType.PHONE).First().contactText 
      }
   );
}
```

I've also tried that to not take null. I don't get the mechanism to tell LINQ not to process if the array is null.

```
phone = c.address.contactItems.Where( ci => ci != null && ci.contactType == ContactType.PHONE).First().contactText
```

Comment: The second query should work, are you sure `address` or `contactItems` isn't `null`?

Comment: You can try using Single() instead of Where and then First. It's more efficient and allow to manage exception.

Comment: What's the problem with posing this query *outside* the object initialisation, thus removing the "need" to do it in one single statement? You're running the risk of making your code decidedly unreadable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check if it's `null` with [`?:`(conditional) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
phone = c.address.contactItems == null ? ""
    : c.address.contactItems.Where( ci => ci.contactType == ContactType.PHONE).First().contactText
```

If [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) throws an exception because there's no one with `ContactType.PHONE` you can use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) with a custom default value:

```
c.address.contactItems.Where( ci => ci.contactType == ContactType.PHONE)
                      .DefaultIfEmpty(new Contact{contactText = ""})
                      .First().contactText
```

Note that `First` now cannot throw an exception anymore since i've provided a default value.

Comment: Yeah it's good but what if it's not null and that it cannot find an item which has a contactType == PHONE ?

Comment: From OP `in case it's null or to return a empty string ""`

Comment: And to prevent other exceptions use `FirstOrDefault();` and check for `null` result, instead of `Where().First();`

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what I wanted !!! the all thing PLUS DefaultIfEmpty !

Comment: This works in my case as well. Thanks. But First() vs FirstOrDefault(), which one to prefer; any suggestions please?

Comment: @mdhameed they are same, difference is that First throws an exception if there is no item and FirstOrDefault returns the default value in that case(null for reference types). So use First when you are sure that there's at least one(like in my answer with DefaultIfEmpty).

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below (I've assumed that `contactText` is a `string`).

You may want to look at standardising the capitalisation of your public property names to all start with an upper-case letter.

```
foreach (Candidate c in candidates) {
    string contactText =
        c.address.contactItems
            .Where(ci => ci.contactType == ContactType.PHONE)
            .Select(ci => ci.contactText)
            .FirstOrDefault()

    results.Add(
        new Person 
        { 
            firstName = c.firstname,
            lastName = c.Name,
            phone = contactText ?? string.Empty
        });
}
```

Comment: `.Where` and `.FirstOrDefault` is redundant in this case and could be simplified

Comment: If you removed the `Where` and `FirstOrDefault` it wouldn't work.  Can you expand on your comment?

Comment: could be `c.address.contactItems.FirstOrDefault(ci => ci.contactType == ContactType.PHONE).Select(ci => ci.contactText)` (I think, didn't test but should be correct)

Comment: Close, but if you `FirstOrDefault` first you run the risk of then later trying to `Select` a property from a `null` object.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var contact = c.address.contactItems.Where( ci => ci.contactType == ContactType.PHONE).FirstOrDefault();
 phone = contact != null ? contact.contactText : "";
```

Comment: I cannot declare var inside the new Response {} statement

Comment: No, but you can do it outside, in the scope of the foreach.

Answer (score 1):

the `null` value is `contactType` so we add `(ci.contactType != null)`

```
    var phone = c.address.contactItems.Where( ci => (ci.contactType != null) && ci.contactType == ContactType.PHONE).First().contactText
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Candidate c in candidates) {
results.Add(new Person 
  { 
     firstName = c.firstname, //ok
     lastName = c.Name, //ok

     // contactItems is an array of ContactItem
     // so it can be null that's why I get null exception 
     // when it's actually null
     phone = c.address.contactItems == null
          ? string.Empty
          :c.address.contactItems.Where( ci => ci.contactType == ContactType.PHONE).First().contactText 
  }
```

);
}

Answer (score 0):

avoid the argument null exception in linq like below

```
 Summaries = (from r in Summaries
              where r.Contains(SearchTerm)
              orderby r
              select r).ToArray();
```

In this case, if null passed to searchTerm you can check the null expression like below

```
 Summaries = (from r in Summaries
              where string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm) ||r.Contains(SearchTerm)
              orderby r
              select r).ToArray();
```

It work's for me!