# How to check for NullReferenceException in LINQ result

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a LINQ query that works fine with EF in my DAL:

```
        using (var mLEntities = new myLab02Entities1())
        {
            var test = from c in mLEntities.Chemicals
                       from u in c.Usages
                       select new
                       {
                           cChemID = c.Chem_ID,
                           c.Name,
                           c.Supplier,
                           c.Grade,
                           c.OrderNo,
                           c.BatchNo,
                           c.EntryDate,
                           c.CreatedBy,
                           cUser = u.Person.PersName,
                           uChemID = u.Chem_ID,
                           u.Study_ID,
                           u.UsedBy,
                           uUser = u.Person.PersName,
                           u.UseDate,
                           u.Project.StudyNo,
                           u.Project.ProjectName,
                       };
```

Usages is a Navigation property of Chemicals (1 chem : n usa), and Person and Projects are both Navigation properties of Usages (both 1 : 1). 
Then I wanted to put this query in my Business Logic and wrote:

```
        IList<ChemicalBDO> chemicalListBDO = chemListDAO.GetChemicalsListFromDB();

        var test = from c in chemicalListBDO
                   from u in c.Usages
                   select new
                   {
                       cChemID = c.Chem_ID,
                       c.Name,
                       c.Supplier,
                       c.Grade,
                       c.OrderNo,
                       c.BatchNo,
                       c.EntryDate,
                       c.CreatedBy,
                       cUser = u.Person.PersName,
                       uChemID = u.Chem_ID,
                       u.Study_ID,
                       u.UsedBy,
                       uUser = u.Person.PersName,
                       u.UseDate,
                       u.Project.StudyNo,
                       u.Project.ProjectName
                   };
```

That is, I first query my EF DBcontext and get my Chemicals Entity, and than I write a query against this Chemicals Entity. 
For me the strange thing is that the last Code throws a System.NullReferenceExeption, because u.Person and u.Project can be NULL. But the first query does not throw exceptions, what is the reason for that? 
How can I handle the NULL reference in the select query, can I check for NULL with "if", "?" or "??" ?

Btw: I thought having the complex query in the DAL is no good programming practice, is that true or can I let the Code there?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14260113/821681

Comment: Johnny: I didn't see that post before and I will have a look at it, thank you. Hucky

Comment: Anytime. I am not sure if it will completely solve your issue, but it looked like it had potential so I decided to share it.  Good luck!

Comment: Use the Elvis operator: `u.Project?.ProjectName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix this problem:

```
IList<ChemicalBDO> chemicalListBDO = chemListDAO.GetChemicalsListFromDB();

    var test = from c in chemicalListBDO
               from u in c.Usages
               select new
               {
                   cChemID = c.Chem_ID,
                   c.Name,
                   c.Supplier,
                   c.Grade,
                   c.OrderNo,
                   c.BatchNo,
                   c.EntryDate,
                   c.CreatedBy,
                   cUser = u.Person != null ? u.Person.PersName : string.Empty,
                   uChemID = u.Chem_ID,
                   u.Study_ID,
                   u.UsedBy,
                   uUser = u.Person != null ? u.Person.PersName : string.Empty,
                   u.UseDate,
                   u.Project != null ? u.Project.StudyNo : -1, 
                   u.Project != null ? u.Project.ProjectName : string.Empty
               };
```

Comment: Hi brugi82: I tested your suggestion but it does not work. I think the problem is that the whole objects u.Person and u.Project are NULL and not only the PersName and StudyNo properties. Hucky

Comment: Well if that is the case solution above would work. You see that we are checking if u.Person is not null and then we are accessing u.Person.PersName. If it is null, then we are setting just string.Empty.

Comment: Are you sure that c.Usages is not null if it's empty? That could also throw null reference exception.

Comment: I am not sure that I know exactly what the problem is. The Usages table in SQL server always contains an entry "Chem_ID", but when this chemical was received in the lab, but never used, the Project and Person tables do not have an entry. In these cases, the first query result in "chemicalListBDO" contains entries in the Usages navigation property, but the Persons and Projects navigation properties are null. I think I have to test whether these properties are NULL, and if not, then I have to get e.eg. u.Project.StudyNo. I will test this in 8 h in the evening.

Comment: I am coming nearer to a solution. The line with cUser is irrelevant, I do not need this result. For uUser, I can write: uUser = u.Chem_ID != null ? u.Person.PersName : string.Empty, or for the last 2 lines I can write: StudyNo = u.Study_ID != null ? u.Project.StudyNo : string.Empty, and  ProjectName = u.Study_ID != null ? u.Project.ProjectName : string.Empty (Study_No is string). The bad thing is, it works either for Person or Project, not for both at the same time. I'll try to find something in Google.