# C# conditional lambda instead of if statements. Value cannot be null error

Tags: c#, lambda, null, conditional-statements

I get this error: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. But that is the point right? if `.FreeAmount` is null it should check in the `AmountList` for a Selected amount. However it fails doing so. I can't really see what I have done wrong here.

```
var amount = string.IsNullOrEmpty(formModel.FreeAmount)
  ? formModel.AmountList
      .Where(x => x.Selected)
      .Select(a => a.Value)
      .SingleOrDefault()
  : formModel.FreeAmount;
```

Comment: Have you checked if formModel is null?

Comment: Is there a SelectedAmount in AmountList ?

Comment: Please include `formModel`'s class as welll as `AmountList`'s class.

Comment: @Kostis if `fromModel` was null then you would get `NullReferenceException`, not `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: Just a suggestion: `formModel.AmountList.Where(x => x.Selected).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Select(a => a.Value).SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: @mcalex the AmountList is a List<SelectListItem>

Comment: @RufusL You removed your comment but you were in fact right. :)

Comment: What was right @Phil_TheAverage?  
Is `formModel.AmountList` null?

Comment: @mjwills yes you were right. I was shocked with this fact that the model binding works but doesn't work with the list but with every other property. The actual problem was our custom html helper that did not map correctly :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [null reference exception with linq .where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259991/null-reference-exception-with-linq-where-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only get a `System.ArgumentNullException` in the code you posted if both `FreeAmount` and `AmountList` are null. If there is some other default value you want to use in this case, you could do something like:

```
var amount = string.IsNullOrEmpty(formModel.FreeAmount)
    ? formModel.AmountList == null
        ? "Default value if FreeAmount and AmountList are null"
        : formModel.AmountList
            .Where(x => x.Selected)
            .Select(a => a.Value)
            .SingleOrDefault()
    : formModel.FreeAmount;
```

Otherwise, if you just want it to return `null` in this case (which I suppose is more likely, since that's currently a possibility with `SingleOrDefault`) then you can just use the null-conditional operator (`?.`):

```
var amount = string.IsNullOrEmpty(formModel.FreeAmount)
    ? formModel.AmountList? // <-- The '?' will return null if AmountList is null
        .Where(x => x.Selected)
        .Select(a => a.Value)
        .SingleOrDefault()
    : formModel.FreeAmount;
```

Answer (score -1):

In the above statement,

Left had side of the ternary operator can result in NULL if formModel is NULL,

So, `string.IsNullOrEmpty(formModel.FreeAmount)` => will result in TRUE.

So, the ternary operator will evaluate left side (true) of the : symbol which is,

```
formModel.AmountList
      .Where(x => x.Selected)
      .Select(a => a.Value)
      .SingleOrDefault()
```

This will result in System.ArgumentNullException because formModel value is null.

So, in the case of formModel being NULL the command will fail with System.ArgumentNullException.

Comment: This is not correct. If `formModel` is null then `formModel.FreeAmount` will throw a `NullReferenceException`. It will never execute `string.IsNullOrEmpty` nor get to the ternary operator.

Comment: It could get into the ternary if `formModel.FreeAmount` was instead `formModel?.FreeAmount` - but even so the ternary would still throw a `NullReferenceException`.